# How to handle Click event or any other Event in GWT Cloud?

Tags: gwt, tags, gwt-rpc, tag-cloud

I am using tagcloud_0.4.jar for using Tag Cloud in GWT. Now, when I click on any tag inside the tag cloud, then how can I handle that event or how can I do RPC call when user select any tag from cloud?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to catch a ClickEvent on the cloud. But this is a workaround as the library may change. As the developper do not offer to manage events on the cloud neither on tags, this is perhaps for a good reason...

So use this code at your own risk. Pray for no change of the widget's structure DOM. I suggest you to ask the developper some enhancements on its widgets, like managing such events.

```
    final TagCloud cloud = new TagCloud();

    cloud.addWord(new WordTag("AAA"));
    cloud.addWord(new WordTag("AAA"));
    cloud.addWord(new WordTag("BBB"));
    cloud.addWord(new WordTag("CCC"));
    cloud.addWord(new WordTag("CCC"));
    cloud.addWord(new WordTag("CCC"));

    cloud.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // Prevent the click from the tag to be executed
            event.preventDefault();

            Element e;
            // For each tag present in the cloud, look for the one that is triggered
            for (int i = 0; i < cloud.getTags().size(); ++i) {
                // Gets the element in the cloud, this really is the unsafe part of the code
                // if the developer change the dom of its widget
                e = DOM.getChild(DOM.getChild(cloud.getElement(), 0), i);
                // Is the current element targeted by the event?
                if (event.getClientX() >= e.getOffsetLeft() && event.getClientY() >= e.getOffsetTop()
                        && event.getClientX() <= e.getOffsetLeft() + e.getOffsetWidth()
                        && event.getClientY() <= e.getOffsetTop() + e.getOffsetHeight()) {
                    // Gets the abstract tag
                    Tag t = cloud.getTags().get(i);
                    // Gets tag descendant
                    if (t instanceof WordTag) {
                        // Do what you want with your WordTag, maybe an RPC call
                    } else if (t instanceof ImageTag) {
                        // Do what you want with your ImageTag, maybe an RPC call
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
```